# JPA query not accepting - " ' " [single quotes]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need your help and I am stuck for last 2 days.Tried looking for solution everywhere but no luck.

I am trying to convert the below query to JPA query.

```
delete from the_table
where the_timestamp < now() - interval '7 days'
```

JPA query is

```
EntityManagerFactory em = tx.getEntityManagerFactory();
em.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("delete from the_table where the_timestamp < now() - interval ?").setParameter(1, "'" +"7 days"+ "'").executeUpdate();
```

And I am getting the below error:-

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Also tried with the parameter based binding, but the issue remained same .below is the snippet

```
EntityManagerFactory em = tx.getEntityManagerFactory();
em.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("delete from the_table where the_timestamp < now() - interval :deleteOlderRecords").setParameter("deleteOlderRecords", "'" +"7 days"+ "'").executeUpdate();
```

Could someone please point out what is the problem here?

Comment: You need to escape the single quote in jpql, which is using `''` instead of `'`

Comment: escaping any single quote won't help you one iota ... there is no "interval" keyword in JPQL

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about JPA but in JDBC you cannot pass an interval like that. You need to use something like this:

```
"delete from the_table where the_timestamp < now() - interval '1' day * ?"
```

And then pass the number of days as an integer

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid (there is no keyword "interval" in JPQL - read any decent JPQL reference). If you want to put in a timestamp then you are best to use a parameter. Alternatively you can use JDBC escape syntax like this link shows
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/jpql.html#literals